# Merge two Arrays by Values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this Array:

```
$mergedItems = array(
  0 => array(
    'id_item' => 'AZ-110'
    'amount' => 12
  ),
  1 => array(
    'id_item' => 'BZ-110',
    'amount' => 13
  ),
  2 => array(
    'id_item' => 'BZ-210',
    'amount' => 28
  ),
  3 => array(
    'id_item' => 'CZ-291',
    'amount' => 11
  )
);
```

AND this **Array**:

```
$items = array(
  0 => array(
    'number' => 'AZ-110'
  ),
  1 => array(
    'number' => 'BZ-110'
  ),
  2 => array(
    'number' => 'CZ-291'
  ),
  3 => array(
    'number' => 'BZ-210'
  )
);
```

Now what i want is to order the first array by the `id_item` Value to match the same order than the 2nd one by its values.

The resulting array has to include all values of the 2nd array AND the belonging amount-value of the first array. The Keys must not be kept!

I can't use `array_merge` since the 2nd Array has a dynamic amount of more items, so i only want all items from the second Array that are set in the first one.

Does anyone get what i mean? I am searching for a quick and non-dirty way to get this result as expected.

/Edit:

Expected Array:

```
$detailedItems = array(
  0 => array(
    'number' => 'AZ-110',
    'amount' => 12
  ),
  1 => array(
    'number' => 'BZ-110',
    'amount' => 13
  ),
  2 => array(
    'number' => 'CZ-291',
    'amount' => 11
  ),
  3 => array(
    'number' => 'BZ-210',
    'amount' => 28
  )
);
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample array output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A PHP 5.5 solution:

```
$itemMap = array_flip(array_column($mergedItems, 'id_item'));
$result = array_map(
    function($i) use($itemMap, $mergedItems) { 
        return $mergedItems[$itemMap[$i['number']]];
    },
    $items);

print_r($result);
```

For 5.3 <= PHP < 5.5 you can simply substitute `array_map` for `array_column`:

```
$itemMap = array_flip(array_map(
    function($i) { return $i['id_item']; },
    $mergedItems));
```

#### How it works

The idea is to create a map of item numbers to indexes inside `$mergedItems`, ie.

```
[
    'AZ-100' => 0,
    'BZ-110' => 1,
    'BZ-210' => 2,
    // etc
]
```

With this information at hand it's very easy to iterate over `$items` (so that the result will be ordered based on that array) and pick the appropriate element from `$mergedItems` to append to the result each time.

Comment: The problem is the switched order of the items in 1st and 2nd array.. :/

So i can walk through the $itemMap in a foreach and get the values of the 1st Array (which is right, by using the foreach-key) but then the last two items of the 2nd array are exchaned (dynamically) so i have no clue how to get the necessary values of the 2nd array to append them to the new built one

Comment: Thanks!

This helped me out. I used your method to walk through the $itemMap and made sth like this:

$new[$itemMapKey] = $items[$cartNbr][self::array_multisearch($key, $items[$cartNbr])];

which used this function:

private static function array_multisearch($id, $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['number'] === $id) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a "non-dirty" (meaning single line) way to do this as far as I know, but this function should work:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($mergedItems as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $detailedItems)) { // Make sure it exists to prevent errors
        $out[$key] = $detailedItems[$key] + array('amount' => $value['amount']);
    } else {
        $out[$key] = $value['amount'];
    }
}
print_r($out);
```

Comment: I've tested it and seems to be working perfectly, outputs just what you requested.

Comment: @ConnorPeet: This cannot possibly work as required because it iterates over `$mergedItems` as its main data source. The question clearly states that the authority on what should be returned and in what order is `$items`; `$mergedItems` just contains the dumb data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = $items;

foreach($temp as &$val)
{
     foreach($mergedItems as $item)
     {
         if($item['id_item'] == $val['number'])
         {
             $val['amount'] = $item['amount'];
             break;
         }
     }
}

print_r($temp);
```

Comment: This one's missing the "amount"-value of the 1st Array :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try following codes:

```
foreach ($mergedItems as $item) {
    $merged[$item['id_item']] = array('amount' => $item['amount']);
}

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $detailedItems[] = array_merge($item, $merged[$item['number']]);
}
```

#### Output

```
var_dump($detailedItems);

array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'AZ-110' (length=6)
      'amount' => int 12
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'BZ-110' (length=6)
      'amount' => int 13
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'CZ-291' (length=6)
      'amount' => int 11
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => string 'BZ-210' (length=6)
      'amount' => int 28
```

Comment: The Output here is not the same as yours :/
$New has two keys containing null,
$merged has 4 arrays which keys are the id_item value only containg the amount value

Comment: @user2610087 I just copy and paste your `$mergedItems` and `$items` array